# A few questions about linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

$\phi \in \alpha(R^3,R^3)$

$B_c:\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
     1&2&3 \\
     0&3&4 \\
     -1&2&1
  \end{array}\right) = [F]_C$

1. Determine the analytic form of the operator $f(x,y,z)$  $x,y,z \in R^3$
2. $f^{-1}$ in $B=\{(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(1,0,0)\}$

Can anybody give me the general steps in solving this kind of problems?

1.
$B_c=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$

$(x,y,z)=xe_1+ye_2+ze_3$

I understand it so far.

$f(x,y,z)=xf(e_1)+yf(x_2)+zf(x_3)$

Why do we apply the function to the bases vectors and not to the x,y,z?

$x(e_1-e_3)+y(2e_1+3e_2+2e_3)+z(2e_1+4e_2+e_3)$

Tell me please, what is the $f(e_i)$ doing, I guess then I'll understand why I should take this combination

Comment: A linear transformation always leaves the coefficients unchanged, and thus we have only to know what it does to the basis vectors, in order to determine the action of the transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix of the operator $f$ with respect to the basis $B_c$ (is this what your notation $[F]_C$ refers to?) tells you the values of $f$ on this basis. For example, the first column tells you that

$$f(e_1) = 1\cdot e_1 + 0\cdot e_2 + (-1)\cdot e_3 = e_1-e_3.$$

Then if we want to compute the value of $f(x,y,z)$ for an arbitrary vector $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, it would be useful to decompose this vector in terms of $B_c$ and then exploit the linearity of $f$.

Now, the notation $e_i$ usually refers to the standard basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose entries are all zero except for the $i$th entry, which is 1. In the case above, we have
$$e_1 = (1,0,0),
e_2 = (0,1,0), e_3 = (0,0,1).$$

An arbitrary vector $(x,y,z)$ can be written as a linear combination of this particular basis in a simple way:

$$(x,y,z) = x(1,0,0) + y(0,1,0) + z(0,0,1)$$

$$= xe_1 + ye_2 + ze_3.$$

So if we want to calculate $f(x,y,z)$, just apply $f$ to both sides:

$$f(x,y,z) = f( xe_1 + ye_2 + ze_3).$$

Now using the fact that $f$ is a linear operator, we can expand the right-hand side:

$$f(x,y,z) = xf(e_1) + yf(e_2) + zf(e_3).$$

From here, you can read off the values $f(e_i)$ from the matrix.

To answer your question about why we don't apply $f$ to the numbers $x,y,z$: the linear operator $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. So it only makes sense to evaluate $f(v)$ where $v$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. a triple of real numbers, rather than a single real number. However, the fact that $f$ is a *linear* operator means that it is *compatible* with multiplication by real numbers, in the sense that

$$f(cv) = cf(v)$$ whenever $c$ is a real number and $v$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Linearity also means that $f(v+w) = f(v) + f(w)$ for all $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Combining these two facts is how the right-hand side of the above equation was expanded.